# How should I copy values from inside a thread back to the main thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, unreal-engine4

I have a function that streams data into my application in a thread, in class (A).
The data is copied into a custom struct (StructStore) in the header file of another class(B):

.h

```
class Data:
public:
    StructStore DataStore;
```

.cpp

```
    Data dd;

    StructStore DataIn;  // data streams in

   dd.DataStore = DataIn;
```

When I add a breakpoint and check the values here (inside the thread), they are as i would expect, both in the DataStore, and the DataIn.

What I need, is to call these values from outside the thread, in yet another class (C). I am trying:

.cpp

```
   StructStore Result;
    Data d;

    Result = d.DataStore;
```

When I check the values here, they are always zero. What am I doing wrong here? How can I copy these values to outside the thread safely?

Comment: You probably want to protect yourself from race conditions, and use some protection mechanism like `std::mutex`.

Comment: What threading library are you using? Is it possible to provide a [minimal code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least a bit more ?

Comment: I am writing a plugin for unreal engine, the threading is done using the FRunnable class:

https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Core/HAL/FRunnableThread/index.html

Comment: @anti I've added the [tag:unreal-engine4] tag, so now provide a [MCVE] for this framework that reproduces your problem please.

Comment: Isn't this a "producer-consumer" type of scenario? Why not have a shared data-structure (std::queue<StructStore>) between the producing stream and consuer!

Comment: Are you clear on the difference between objects and types? Because you seem to assume that two objects share a value just because they share a type (?!). That's not how it works, not at all. You can have thousands of integers, all the same type, all different values. And you can have many `Data` and `StructStore` objects, each with their own values.

Comment: I understood that creating an instance of a class, such as 'Data dd;', then using 'dd.DataStore;' would reference the values of the 'DataStore' struct that exists in 'Data'. Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

One easy and safe (but not the 100% most efficient) way is to use a [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe).  Just have your main thread read from it (either blocking if only one worker thread, or using `select()` if multiple pipes to wait on).  Then have your worker thread `write()` the struct to it.  You can even have multiple threads writing to the pipe at the same time without locking if the size of each write is less than `PIPE_BUF` bytes.

Comment: Thanks! Is this an option on windows?

Comment: it will be very slow for a  3d-shooter game. I suggest you to look here http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/threads-sharing-data